# Why the mirrored paste mirrors the wrong way

Tags: animation

I created my character and its armature, now I'm on the stage of creating actions. I am creating my in-place walk action and my first 2 key-frames. when copying the key-frames and pasting the mirrored version with (Ctrl+Shift+V), it mirrored on the y axis instead of the X.

Can someone please help me, thanks.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: For animation I would recommend maya or 3ds max. This is a serious weak area for the software, and its not worth going down with the ship. Thw only advice I have is to turn on x-axis mirror in the left hand toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't think you can actually turn the x-axis mirror since its a check box. -

Comment: > "turn on" tho